# Sequence of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

A friend of mine did an exercise where a part of the text was:

> In $\mathbb{R}^3$, with euclidian topology, we consider $X=\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \{ N \}$, where $N= (0,0,1)$ and $E=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{S}^2 \mid z=0 \}$. Let be $Y= X/E$ the quotient space obtained from the contraction of $E$ to one point and let $\pi\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be the canonical projection

Now a game started in my mind.

I know that $Y$ is homeomorphic to two spheres, one of which has a point removed. Now let $X=X_0$ and $Y=X_1$. For each sphere of $X_1$, I'll do the same thing that i did to $Y$ so I'll have $X_2$ that is homeomorphic to $4$ spheres where one of these is without a point. I know that $\mathbb{S}_2 \setminus \{ N \}$ is homeomorphic to a close disk $D^2$. So I create a sequence $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} $ of topological spaces where each $X_i$ is homeomorphic to $2^i-1$ spheres tangent where the last one is tangent to a disk. 
The question is:

> Is it possible to determinate the space $$\lim_{i \to \infty}X_i$$

Is it a topological space? Does this sequence converges?

Are we in the space of the topological space? Which kind of space is this?

Sorry for my bad english, i hope someone will fix my errors.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by limit?

Comment: I don't know. It's possible to consider the limit of this sequence? Or is a my "invention"?.. Another question.. Where are we?.. In which space?.. What is the space of the topologycal space?.. We can define a norm?..

Comment: No, it does not make sense to take the limit of topological spaces without any additional data. It *is* possible to take a limit of compact metric spaces. See Gromov-Hausdorff metric. (Just as with any sequence of points in a metric space, though, this limit may not exist!)

Comment: @DanRust It was correct $2^i-1$

Comment: @Skills my edit must have reverted it somehow.

Comment: Hmm. Unless I misunderstood we have compatible maps $\pi_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$ whenever $i\le j$, so [a direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) is probably what you want.

Comment: @MikeMiller Suppose that we start from $S^2$ and not from $S^2 \setminus \{N \}$. Does it make sense?

Comment: Jyrki's comment is more relevant than mine.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've never heard about it. I'll read it. Thanks

Comment: The direct limit is probably what you want. I'm going to hazard a guess that the direct limit is a countable 'necklace' of spheres (with a disk attached), although it's possible something more subtle happens.

Comment: I don't have anything to add to that Wikipedia page. Do observe that the end result will have the [final topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology). My guess is that you will be contracting all the latitudes that have a $z$-coordinate of the form $k/2^n$ for some integers $k,n$ to single points. I do not have a clear intuitive picture of what the topology will be like. Looks very weird :-)

Comment: @DanRust What do you mean with "necklace"?

Comment: I think my guess of the 'necklace' is wrong. If we ignore the missing point, so that $X_i$ is compact, then the direct limit will be compact, being the image of a compact space. @JyrkiLahtonen is more likely to be correct. Every neighbourhood of every point in the direct limit will have a preimage in one of the $X_i$s which contains an entire sphere.

Comment: Yes it's very weird. I'll study more topology for find a solution. Thank you all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll ignore the missing point at the north pole for now as it doesn't really add anything to the picture as far as I can tell.

I think this space could be considered some kind of bastard demon-spawn of the [line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins).

You could so something very similar to you example, except start with a copy of the circle in the plane, glue together the east and westmost points to get $X_1$, then form $X_2$ which is four circles, and so on and so forth.

In the same way that you can think of the line with two origins as being two copies of the real line line glued together point for point *except* for the origin, I think the direct limit of these circular $X_i$ will be $$(I\times\{0\}\sqcup I\times \{1\})/{\sim}$$ where $(x,0)\sim (y,1)$ if and only if $x=y=k/2^n$ for some $n\geq 0$ and integer $0\leq k \leq 2^n$.

I think the best way I could try to imagine the direct limit in the *spherical* case of the $X_i$s is something like the above defined space 'rotated about its axis', so instead of every point not of the form $k/2^n$ having exactly two representatives, we now have an entire **circle** worth of representatives, all points of which have open neighbourhoods which will always intersect non-trivially.